# Check if a pointer points to statically allocated object?

Tags: c++, qt

I have implemented some leak detector of QObjects. To make long story short, During the removing of static objects I check what QObject was not removed.
But the problem is that some QObject is allocated staticly so I need to remove them from leak report.
Is there are way to know if pointer points to statically allocated object?

Comment: What is this leak report? There are a bunch of utilities that already do this, so I wonder if you're re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: This question is related to: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3065092/694576 if not a duplicate to the latter.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, there are no portable way to know what duration type a variable uses by simply knowing its address. But provided all your dynamic allocations use `new` you could use your own *replacement functions* for the different signatures of `operator new` and `operator delete`, and use them to manage a map or a set of all allocations. Reference in current C++ standard draft n4296:

> 17.6.4.6 Replacement functions [replacement.functions]
>
> ...
>   A C++ program may provide the definition for any of twelve dynamic memory allocation function signatures
>   declared in header <new> (3.7.4, 18.6):
>
> - operator new(std::size_t)
> - operator new(std::size_t, const std::nothrow_t&)
> - operator new
> - operator new[](std::size_t, const std::nothrow_t&)
> - operator delete(void*)
> - operator delete(void*, const std::nothrow_t&)
> - operator delete
> - operator delete[](void*, const std::nothrow_t&)
> - operator delete(void*, std::size_t)
> - operator delete(void*, std::size_t, const std::nothrow_t&)
> - operator delete[](void*, std::size_t)
> - operator delete[](void*, std::size_t, const std::nothrow_t&)
>
> The program’s definitions are used instead of the default versions supplied by the implementation (18.6).
>   Such replacement occurs prior to program startup (3.2, 3.6). The program’s declarations shall not be
>   specified as inline. No diagnostic is required.

That would allow you to build a kind of *hand made* valgrind and store for example in an array - usage of standard containers inside operator new could be tedious because they do use operator new! - the list of allocated blocks. At a simple level something like that could help:

```
// use a SZ value big enough for your program...
#define SZ 1000
struct Alloc {
    void *p;
    size_t size;
} alloc[SZ];

bool inited = false;

void * operator new(size_t s) {
    void * p = malloc(s);
    if (p != NULL) {
        // fprintf(stderr, "Allocate %d at %p\n", s, p); // for debug
        for (int i=0; i<SZ; i++) {
            if (alloc[i].p == NULL) {
                alloc[i].p = p;
                alloc[i].size = s;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return p;
}

void operator delete(void *p) {
    size_t s = 0;
    if (p != NULL) {
        for (int i=0; i<SZ; i++) {
            if (alloc[i].p == p) {
                s = alloc[i].size;
                alloc[i].p = NULL;
                break;
            }
        }
        free(p);
    }
    // fprintf(stderr,"De-allocate %p (%d)\n", p, s); // for debug
}
```

Note that I deliberately use C stdio functions for debugging traces to avoid any possibility of C++ allocation memory calls in C++ standard library io.