# Checking if a pointer is in a malloc'd area?

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

I'm making a dynamic memory allocator and I need to check than when I'm freeing a section of it, that the pointer I'm passing into the function is in fact within that area. I have a pointer to the beginning of the malloc'd area

```
typedef unsigned char byte;

static byte *memory // pointer to start of allocator memory
```

which I assign in my initiating function.  I also have the size of the malloc'd area stored in

```
static u_int33_t memory_size;   // number of bytes malloc'd in memory[]
```

How do I ensure that the ptr isnt... (in pseudo code)

```
ptr < *memory || ptr > *memory + memory_size
```

and that code results in the following error;

error: comparison of distinct pointer types lacks a cast [-Werror]
    if ( object < memory || object > (memory + memory_size))
                ^

I'm not sure what I need to cast and what not to...

The free function is as follows...

```
void memfree(void *object)
{
   if ( object < memory || object > (memory + memory_size)) {
  fprintf(stderr, "vlad_free: Attempt to free via invalid pointer\n");
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }
}
```

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3065092/check-if-a-pointer-points-to-allocated-memory-on-the-heap

Comment: So, your dynamic allocator has a single reservoir of memory to allocate, which is necessarily all contiguous?  What is the type of `byte`?  What is the type of `u_int33_t`?  What goes wrong with the expression you propose?  How portable does your code have to be?

Comment: @Jaime: I think the question you reference is more general than the problem posed in this question.

Comment: sorry, typedef unsigned char byte;
and portability isn't a concern

Comment: In future, please add requested information to the question — you can edit your own question.  I've added the typedef for `byte` for you.

Comment: None of this makes much sense. Are you trying to write your own malloc or something?

Answer (score 0):

### Original

**This is wrong as pointed out by [Raymond Chen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39161283/5129715)**

```
void memfree(void *_object)
{
   byte* object = (byte*)_object;
   if ( object >= memory && object < (memory + memory_size)) {
       /* defined guarantees - they happened to be in the same object. */
   } else {
      fprintf(stderr, "memfree: Attempt to free via invalid pointer\n");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }
}
```

The types of pointers need to be the same.  Given that you seem to have a range in bytes, it seems best to use byte.

From the C standard [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)

> When two pointers are compared, the result depends on the relative locations in the
>   address space of the objects pointed to. If two pointers to object types both point to the
>   same object, or both point one past the last element of the same array object, they
>   compare equal. If the objects pointed to are members of the same aggregate object,
>   pointers to structure members declared later compare greater than pointers to members
>   declared earlier in the structure, and pointers to array elements with larger subscript
>   values compare greater than pointers to elements of the same array with lower subscript values. All pointers to members of the same union object compare equal. If the
>   expression P points to an element of an array object and the expression Q points to the
>   last element of the same array object, the pointer expression Q+1 compares greater than
>   P. In all other cases, the behavior is undefined.

Here, I believe the undefined behavior, is that you can't tell if on 2 systems, that there will be a consistent ordering,  so code which uses `a < b`, may be true on some systems and false on others.

### New answer

Use

```
void memfree(void *_object)
{
   uintptr_t object = (uintptr_t)_object;
   if ( object >= (uintptr_t)memory && object < ((uintptr_t)memory + (uintptr_t)memory_size)) {
       /* defined guarantees - they happened to be in the same object. */
   } else {
      fprintf(stderr, "memfree: Attempt to free via invalid pointer\n");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }
}
```

Comment: Comparing pointers, using relational operators, that don't belong to the same object is undefined behavior.

Comment: Your edit implies as if the behavior is consistent on separate architectures. It isn't, and the result isn't false or true, it is simply undefined.

Comment: Understood - that you are representing the consensus in stack overflow, but I can't believe this is what was meant by the designers of the language, in fact if it is possible to have a pointer which happens to point within the bounds, then other rules will be false (conversion to and from different types doesn't affect the value of the pointer).  So I believe my interpretation is correct

Comment: The last line of the standard is very clear: *in all other cases, the behavior is undefined*, which is what happens if a pointer that doesn't point to object memory, is passed to memfree.